# Losing table data on second using ElementList

Tags: java, itext

Situation (my task): I need calculate table of contents. My process look like data -> java classes -> xml -> xslt -> html -> parsing to ElementList -> analize element list -> making pdf. On the stage 'xslt' I add marker for points of (future) table contents. On the stage 'analize element list' I make table of contents and clear markers in the Element of ElementList. Up to this point there are no problems. For correct location points page number I have to form pdf several times. The problem occurs when I create a second (or more) time pdf. It looks like the absence of some content (it can be text and / or pictures) in the tables - not all of them disappear.

After first pdf making all content is present.
If use second instance ElementList with parsed elements for second pdf making content correct.

What's a problem in resusing ElementList and how fix it ?

ps. itext-5.5.11 + xmlparser-5.5.11

pps. sorry for my poor English

```
private void test() throws DocumentException, IOException {
    // step 1: get parsed elements
    ElementList list = contentElement.get(BODY).getElements();

    // step 2: bytes for first pdf
    byte[] bytes = getBytes(list);

    // step 3: file 1
    File out = new File("1.pdf");
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(out);
    fos.write(bytes);
    fos.close();

    // step 4: reuse ElementList
    bytes = getBytes(list);

    // step 5: file 2
    out = new File("2.pdf");
    fos = new FileOutputStream(out);
    fos.write(bytes);
    fos.close();

    // Why will it be two different file ?
}

private byte[] getBytes(ElementList list) throws DocumentException, IOException {
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    Rectangle page = new Rectangle(PageSize.A4);
    page = page.rotate();
    Document doc = new Document(page, 56, 42, 10, 10);
    Rectangle body = new Rectangle(56, 60, 800, 525);
    writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(doc, baos);
    writer.setPageEvent(this);
    doc.open();
    ColumnText text = new ColumnText(writer.getDirectContent());

    for (Element element : list) {

        text.setText(null);
        text.addElement(element);
        boolean makeNewPage =  ColumnText.hasMoreText(text.go());
        while (makeNewPage) {
            doc.newPage();
            text.setSimpleColumn(body);
            makeNewPage = ColumnText.hasMoreText(text.go());
        }
    }
    doc.close();
    byte[] bytes = baos.toByteArray();
    baos.close();
    return bytes;
}
```

Comment: Some processes "consume" content. E.g. when you add elements to a `ColumnText` object, and you render the elements, then those elements are gone. `ColumnText` can be used directly, or indirectly. As you don't show any of your code, nor tell us which version of iText you are using, it is hard to give you a more accurate answer.

Comment: Thanx, for your help, update post: add versions and debug code

Answer (score 0):

The current algorithm not support if div-tag content located into the td-tag. I fixed it - remove div-tag in td-tags.